# How to perform efficient Lookup in Spark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a base table having 2 years of data ~4TB size and this data is appended to this dataset on a daily basis
So this is a ever increasing dataset
Now for my daily processing I am receiving a data ~3GB and first check from this daily file is to find all the id's which are present in my base dataset(~4TB)

```
common_ids= base_data.join(daily_data,base_data.proc_id==daily_data.c_id,"inner")
```

Currently I am doing it by inner join using spark 3.2.0 version
Both my datasets are big so cant broadcast either datasets and my execution time is increasing on a daily basis as my base data set size is increasing on a daily basis as we need to keep 5 years data

Kindly let me know the efficient way to have this lookup

Tried changing repartition value and changing the spark shuffle parameters along with spark 3.2.0 optimisation properties

Comment: Try looping on the partitions

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in the IDs you might want to select them before doing the join? Depending on what your data looks like, it might drastically reduce the size of your join.

```
val base_ids = base_data.select("proc_id")
val daily_ids = daily_data.select("c_id")
val common_ids = base_ids.join(daily_ids,base_ids(proc_id) === daily_ids(c_id), "inner")
```

Comment: No I need to pull all the columns from the base data set and from daily data sets

Comment: The first thing I would do is take a look at whether you've got some slow running tasks in that join. Have a look a the Spark UI (or History Server logs if you've activated those) and look at the time it takes to compute the tasks. Do they all take approximately the same amount of time? Or are there tasks that take waaaay longer than the norm? If the latter, you might have data skew problems. You could try out salting to have a better repartitioning of your data before joining.

Comment: Secondly, it might also be interesting to see how large your total memory across all of your executors is. If that total memory is way smaller than 4TB, it might be that you are spilling A LOT to disk, which is never a super fast operation. In that case, increasing executor RAM could be an interesting path to take (to limit the amount of disk spillage)